# How do i find multiple occurences of this specific string and split them into a list?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a specific piece of string inside a bigger whole of a string.

Here's the string, and the bold words are the ones that i want to extract using the re.findall function inside the re library of python.

> text|p1_1_SNtestfilefri01|**ANTENNA SYSTEM**|@|text|p1_2_SNtestfilefri01|**ALCATEL-LUCENT**|@|text|p1_3_SNtestfilefri01|**MW ANTENNA**|@|text|p1_4_SNtestfilefri01|**DIA 0.6 M 13 GHZ SINGLE POLARIZED**|@|text|p1_5_SNtestfilefri01|**L1AF10018AAAA**|@|text|p1_6_SNtestfilefri01|**SNtestfilefri01**

Here's my code :

```
open_file = open(filepath, mode='r')
doc = open_file.read()
datas = re.findall('\|(.*)\|\@\|', doc)
print(datas)
```

And here's the output :

> ['p1_1_SNtestfilefri01|ANTENNA
>   SYSTEM|@|text|p1_2_SNtestfilefri01|ALCATEL-LUCENT|@|text|p1_3_SNtestfilefri01|MW
>   ANTENNA|@|text|p1_4_SNtestfilefri01|DIA 0.6 M 13 GHZ SINGLE
>   POLARIZED|@|text|p1_5_SNtestfilefri01|L1AF10018AAAA']

What's the correct pattern so that i could achive something like this ? :

> ['ANTENNA SYSTEM','ALCATEL-LUCENT','MW ANTENNA','DIA 0.6 M 13 GHZ SINGLE POLARIZED','L1AF10018AAAA', 'SNtestfilefri01']

Also the string i mentioned above doesn't contain any newline (everything is in a single line)

Comment: How do you know which strings to pick? I mean does the strings to be picked up is always from this set of 5 strings?

Comment: is it like to pick only upper case string ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. @JuhilSomaiya not necessary only upper case string. It's actually happens to be mix of lower & upper string.

Comment: Thanks for the response! @em_bis_me the string i want to acquire is the one inside a bar section("|") and also where the next bar section contains the at ("@") symbol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
re.findall('[^|]+(?=\|\@\|)', doc)
```

Explanation:

- `[^|]+`finds chunks of text not containing the separator
- `(?=...)` is a "lookahead assertion" (match the text but do not include in result)

Comment: Correct answer, Thanks! but i actually had a little problem. I updated the string above to match the actual pattern of the string (the one above was the sliced version to make it easier to read). I don't get the last value of the "bar section" since it ends without |@| .

Comment: @DyaksaHanindito Modify the lookahead to test for the end of the string as well: `re.findall('[^|]+(?=\|\@\||$)', s)`.`|` is an _or_ (matching either operand), and `$` matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty solution, but works was on top of my head:

```
import re

s = "text|p1_1_SNtestfilefri01|ANTENNA SYSTEM|@|text|p1_2_SNtestfilefri01|ALCATEL-LUCENT|@|text|p1_3_SNtestfilefri01|MW ANTENNA|@|text|p1_4_SNtestfilefri01|DIA 0.6 M 13 GHZ SINGLE POLARIZED|@|text|p1_5_SNtestfilefri01|L1AF10018AAAA|@|"

s = s.split('@')
match_list = []

for data in s:
    data += "@|"
    m = re.search('\|(.*)\|(.*)\|\@\|', data)
    if m:
        match_list.append(m.group(2))
```