# Regex - How do i find this specific slice of string inside a bigger whole string

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, text-processing

following my previous question ([How do i find multiple occurences of this specific string and split them into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044758/how-do-i-find-multiple-occurences-of-this-specific-string-and-split-them-into-a)), I'm now going to ask something more since the rule has been changed.

Here's the string, and the bold words are the ones that I want to extract.

> text|p1_1_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**C M E -
>   Rectifier**|@|text|p1_2_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|Huawei|@|text|p1_3_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|Rectifier
>   Module 3KW|@|text|p1_4_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|Shuangdeng
>   6-FMX-170|@|text|p1_5_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|24021665|@|text|p1_6_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|1120170AS074192161A0Z20|@|text|p1_7_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|OK|@|text|p1_8_1120170AS074192161A0Z20||@|text|p1_9_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|ACTIVE|@|text|p1_10_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|-OK|@|text|site_id|20MJK110|@|text|barcode_flag|auto|@|text|movement_flag||@|text|unit_of_measurement||@|text|flag_waste|no|@|text|req_qty_db|2|@|text|req_qty|2

Here's my current regex:

```
    (?<=p1\_1\_.*)[^|]+(?=\|\@\|.*|$)
```

After trying it out in https://regexr.com/, I found the result instead :

> text|p1_1_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**C M E -
>   Rectifier**|@|text|p1_2_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**Huawei**|@|text|p1_3_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**Rectifier
>   Module 3KW**|@|text|p1_4_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**Shuangdeng
>   6-FMX-170**|@|text|p1_5_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**24021665**|@|text|p1_6_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**1120170AS074192161A0Z20**|@|text|p1_7_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**OK**|@|text|p1_8_1120170AS074192161A0Z20||@|text|p1_9_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**ACTIVE**|@|text|p1_10_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**-OK**|@|text|site_id|**20MJK110**|@|text|barcode_flag|**auto**|@|text|movement_flag||@|text|unit_of_measurement||@|text|flag_waste|**no**|@|text|req_qty_db|**2**|@|text|req_qty|**2**

The question remains: "*Why don't just return the first matched occurrence ?*".
Let's consider that if the value between the first "bar section" is empty, then it'll return the value of the next bar section.
Example :

> text|p1_1_1120170AS074192161A0Z20||@|text|p1_2_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|**Huawei**|@|text . . .

And I don't want that. Let it be just return nothing instead (nothing match).

What's the correct regex to acquire such a match?
Thank you :).

Comment: It seems that your input is a CSV format, but instead of the usual `,` the columns are separated with `|`.

Comment: It seems like a CSV format but instead it's "Bar Separated" yeah

Answer (score 1):

This data looks more structured than you are giving it credit for.  A regular expression is great for e.g. extracting email addresses from unstructured text, but this data seems delimited in a straightforward manner.

If there is structure it will be simpler, faster, and more reliable to just split on `|` and perhaps `@`:

```
text = 'text|p1_1_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|C M E - Rectifier|@|text|p1_2_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|Huawei|@|text|p1_3_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|Rectifier Module 3KW|@|text|p1_4_11201...'
lines = text.split('|@|')
words = [line.split('|')[-1] for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doc='text|p1_1_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|C M E - Rectifier|@|text|p1_2_1120170AS074192161A0Z20|Huawei|@|text|...'
re.findall('[^|]+(?=\|\@\|)', doc)
```

In the re expression:

[^|]+finds chunks of text not containing the separator
(?=...) is a "lookahead assertion" (match the text but do not include in result)

Answer (score 0):

About the pattern you tried

- This part of the pattern `[^|]+` states to match any char other than `|`
- Then `(?=\|\@\|.*|$)` asserts using a positive lookahead what is on the right is `|@|.*` or the end of the string.
- The positive lookbehind `(?<=p1\_1\_.*)` asserts what is on the left is `p1_1_` followed by any char except a newline using a quantifier in the lookbehind.

As the pattern is not anchored, you will get all the matches for this logic because the `p1_1_` assertion is true as it precedes all the`|@|` parts

**Note** that using the quantifier in the lookbehind will require the [pypi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

If you want the first match using a quantifier in the positive lookbehind you could for example use an anchor in combination with a negative lookahead to not cross the `|@|` or match `||` in case it is empty:

```
(?<=^.*?p1_1_(?:(?!\|@\|).|\|{2})*\|)[^|]+(?=\|\@\||$)
```

[Python demo](https://rextester.com/JEZJC89499)

---

You could use your original pattern using [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) getting the first match.

```
(?<=p1_1_.*)[^|]+(?=\|\@\||$)
```

**Note** that you don't have to escape the underscore in your original pattern and you can omit `.*` from the positive lookahead

[Python demo](https://rextester.com/KDEY36698)

---

But to get the first match you don't have to use a positive lookbehind. You could also use an anchor, match and capturing group.

```
^.*?p1_1_(?:(?!\|@\|).|\|{2})*\|([^|]+)(?:\|@\||$)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline
- `p1_1_` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!\|@\|).|\|{2}` If what is on the right is not `|@|` match any char, or match 2 times `||`
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\|` Match `|`
- `(` Capture **group 1** (This will contain your value

  - `[^|]+` Match 1+ times any char except `|`
- `)` Close group
- `(?:\|@\||$)` Match either `|@|`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3jzgro/1)